# Accessing FlatBuffers records when dealing with arrays

Tags: c#, flatbuffers

I am trying to understand how to access (multiple) records on `FlatBuffers` The examples that are available are all dealing with a single record. The google example deals with 1x monster record and nothing else. I have seen an example that discusses the schema for multiple records. This example can be found here:

https://medium.com/@brijesh.vicky/steps-to-use-flatbuffers-abbd7addeeb9

In this example, can someone tell me how to access `repos`

Comment: use git to access repo - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/intro-to-git/

Comment: jazb, I was not referring to the repos you are referring to. Please open up the link above then find "repos"

Answer (score 1):

Tests are a great place to learn how to do things in codebases, since they are usually uptodate and provide minimal examples.

Look at how this [test accesses multiple objects](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/tests/FlatBuffers.Test/FlatBuffersExampleTests.cs#L152-L155), where `TestArrayOfTables` is defined [here](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/blob/master/tests/monster_test.fbs#L98). That would be an example of how you could have multiple records in a flatbuffer, and access them with the C# generated code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It is much appreciated. I do not know much about tests. So, I would really appreciate it if you can tell me what to do.